# Python Unittest: How to unittest a decorator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

Here's my sample code which I want to test.

decorator.py

```
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        data_header = request.headers['Authorization']
        token = str.replace(str(data_header), 'Bearer ', '')
        if not token:
            return jsonify({'Message':'Token is missing'}), 401
        try:    
            data = jwt.decode(token, "mysecret", algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            return make_response({'Message':'Invalid Token!'}, 403)
        return f(data, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

get_user_uid.py

```
@getuid_bp.route('/users/<uid>', methods=['GET'])
@token_required
def profile_view(data, uid):
    profile_data = service_profile(data, uid)
    return profile_data
```

data in profile_view(data, uid) is jwt decode value.

I need to test functionalities present in the decorator such as "Token is missing" & "invalid token".

This is what I've tried.

```
    def test_service_user_profile(self):

        data = {                                                              
            "address": "Ahmedabad",
            "dob": "2022-06-07T23:16:20",
            "email_address": "testuser58@example.com",
            "password": "sha256$WbLrMDWEUHKvLDSC$2a051f8689222fc9815cd00da2c3260e114c313ba20edebf8df17e6d409721ac",
            "uid": "75f9d2c5570f4c7bb5e28c5807f92c48",
            "user_name": "testuser58"
             }

        encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(data, "mysecret", algorithm="HS256")
        decoded_jwt = jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, "mysecret", algorithms="HS256")

        data_header = f'Bearer {encoded_jwt}'
    

        m1 = mock.MagicMock()
        m1.headers.return_value = data_header
        print("m", m1)
        
            
        response = profile_view(data,"75f9d2c5570f4c7bb5e28c5807f92c48")
        # mock_profile.assert_called_once()
```

But I'm confused about how to set data in **profile_view(data, uid):** and how to test the decorator. I've tried to mock the request in decorator but I don't know whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: Your provided example is not reproducible. At least the `token_required` function should be complete, yet it seems to assume the existence of a `request`, but no such local variable exists in it. Please include relevant imports and context to allow others to reproduce your setup. If you want to make it easier for other to help you, also try and abstract and condense your problem to the essentials.